# Trouble creating react component to spec

Tags: css, reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to create a react component to match this image:
[Doughnut Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyHTI.png)
But cant seem to get it correct. The component takes a percentage and increases the area of the colour based on that percentage, the dotted line being 100% mark and the outer section being 200%
so at zero percent it will be all white and at 200% and beyond the entire doughnut will be orange

So far I have attempted to solve using css radial gradient but to no avail as the gradient starts from the centre of the entire component so is not visible for roughly the first 60%
I have also looked into highcharts but nothing that I came across seemed to fit the design.
Any suggestion of an library that has a component like this or a recommended way of solving?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This React component creates a ref for both the outer and inner elements of the graph. This is so that the component can access the width of each element to calculate the border width of the graph. In particular, it calculates the maximum intensity of the graph (the difference between the outer and inner widths) and then multiplies that by the value provided to the component to determine the border width. By using a ref, the component is able to access the relevant data needed to calculate the border width without having to re-render the component.

If you decide not to use fixed values in your CSS. Instead you opt for using dynamic sizing via props, then the Refs are not required and can be replaced by your props for calculation.

```
import { createRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import css from './graph.module.css';

export interface GraphProps {
  value: number;
}

function IntensityGraph(props: GraphProps) {
  const [borderWidth, setBorderWidth] = useState<number>(0);
  const outerRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const innerRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const { value } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (outerRef.current !== null && innerRef.current !== null) {
      const { clientWidth: outerWidth } = outerRef.current;
      const { clientWidth: innerWidth } = innerRef.current;
      const maxIntensity = outerWidth - innerWidth;

      setBorderWidth(((maxIntensity / 100) * value) / 4);
    }
  }, [value, setBorderWidth]);

  return (
    <div ref={outerRef} className={css.outer}>
      <div ref={innerRef} className={css.inner} style={{ borderWidth }}>
        <h1>{value}%</h1>
        <h3>Intensity</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default IntensityGraph;
```

```
.outer {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  place-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.15);
  outline-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.2);
  outline-style: dashed;
  outline-offset: -2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
}

.inner {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  place-content: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  color: #242424;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: orange;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  transition: border-width 0.3s linear;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inner > * {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I had to swap out the inner css border code with css outline and it worked exactly as I needed, thank you!